# Allow user to read all files created by root

Tags: bash, ubuntu, permissions

I have a folder where files are continuously created from the user `root`.

Some other tool tries to read these files, but it fails because it has no read permissions.

How can I make it possible for the `user` user to read either all files from `root`, or all files from this directory? Even if new files are always generated.

Comment: Does this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11512211/5395338) help?

Comment: This is a one time change. I want my change to take place from this point on

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the created files have group-read permission, you could change directory group to one which `user` is member of (`chgrp mygroup directory`) and enable `setgid` bit for the directory (`chmod g+s /directory`). New files created to that directory inherit directory's group.

If files have group-read permission but you don't want to use setgid bit you could alternatively use ACLs; set default ACL for directory and allow read permission for group `mygroup` with `setfacl -d -m g:mygroup:rx directory`. New files inherit the default ACL.